# Javascript: Function - Return an Object will invalid this.variable

Tags: javascript, function, this, instance-variables

I m using javascript. Declaring a instance variable "this.variable" will work until my function will return an object. Return of an String, Number doesnt affect it. In the case of returning an object the instance variable doesnt work anymore and become "undefined". Please can you help me!  (Look for a sample at   http://jsfiddle.net/woko/vE4rq/2/  tested under recent versions of firefox & chrome )

```
function Funct() {
    this.varfunc = "this ist a instance";
    return false;
}

var f = new Funct();
console.log(f.varfunc);

function FunctReturnobj() {
    this.varfunc = "this ist a instance + return an object";
    return {};
}

var fr = new FunctReturnobj();
console.log(fr.varfunc)
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in the scope of a function is `DOMWindow`.

`this` in the scope of an object **is** the object.

Answer (score 0):

The `new` operator will create a new object and apply the function on it - `this` in the function scope refers to that object.

But when the function is called without new, or contains a return statement, it won't be executed as a "constructor". `this` will point to the execution context, usually the `window` object.

Comment: thanks a lot, its my solution!! calling a function with a return statement will not be executed as a "constructor"

Answer (score 0):

You're using constructors in a wrong way. Constructors shouldn't return anything themselves. You can use the `prototype` property to declare "class"/object methods or you can set them in the constructor like you already do:

```
function Constructor(value) {
  this.variable = value;
}

var obj = new Constructor('test');
obj.variable; // -> Returns 'test';
```

Same way you can declare methods of you object:

```
function Constructor(value) {
  this.variable = value;

  this.say = function(something) {
    return "I say: " + something;
  };
}
```

Or the prototype way:

```
function Constructor(value) {
  this.variable = value;
}

Constructor.prototype.say = function(something) {
  return "I say: " + something;
};
```

Of course this a generic and kinda bad example, but you probably get the point :)